Magento 2.4.7 sample data doesn't show on the frontend
I'm having a problem on a fresh docker Magento 2.4.7 installation and nothing seems to work to fix it.
I've installed the sample data, it is showing on the backend side, but not on the frontend.
I've just tried to:

Clear cache
Reindex
Check opensearch connection from settings
Check visibility
Check stock

When I enter category pages they are empty.
My custom module is able to search products and retrieve product URLs, when I enter that pages they are empty...
Any idea?
